# Combinatorial condition for orientability on simplicial complexes

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, discrete-geometry, manifolds, simplicial-complexes

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex whose geometric realization is a topological or smooth manifold.

Is it possible to restate the condition of orientability of $M$ exclusively in (combinatorial) terms of $K$? Or at least, is there a sufficient condition on $K$ which guarantees that $M$ is orientable?

*By *combinatorial terms* I mean a condition that can be established on the abstract simplicial complex $K$. Hopefully there exists one apart from looking at the top dimensional simplicial homology (as Oliver suggested). If no other condition is proposed, I will accept that as an answer.

Comment: You will see orientability on top level simplicial homology of $K$.

Comment: Sure @OlivierBégassat but I ask for some combinatorial condition on the face poset which does not involve homology. Thanks anyway for your comment. I mean, if $M$ was a smooth manifold, then we would have at least the definition of orientability with local homology and the differential geometric one. Is there one relying only on the combinatorics of the simplicial complexes which does not require homology?

Comment: What do you mean by the underlying space of a simplicial complex $K$? The only thing I can think of is the geometric realization $|K|$, whose singular homology is isomorphic to the simplicial homology of $K$, so Olivier's comment seems to be a valid answer.

Comment: @MarkGrant you are absolutely right, I should have said geometric realization instead of "underlying space". Oliver's comment is a valid answer and I will accept it. I just was looking for other combinatorial condition which did not involve homology. It may not exist!!

Comment: I edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: I find the question a little confusing.  Could you define what you mean by "combinatorial"? as the homological definition of orientation appears (to me) to be combinatorial when talking about simplicial complexes.

Comment: You can choose an orientation of some facet $F$ of $K$. This induces an orientation of a neighboring facet $F'$. (By "neighboring" I mean they differ in only one vertex.) If every path from $F$ back to $F$ preserves the orientation of $F$, then $K$ is orientable. Of course it's not a very practical condition to check directly, but it is purely combinatorial (no linear algebra).

Comment: Let me phrase @RichardStanley 's comment in a different way. Let $n$ be the dimension. It is orientable iff you can orient each $n$-simplex in such a way that two of them with a common $(n-1)$-face induce opposite orientation on the common $(n-1)$-face. An orientation is an equivalence class of total orderings on the vertices. Two orderings are equivalent if the permutation that relates them is even.